# VM exported and imported . ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g, atg

Hi i have exported my vm and imported it to other machine (laptop) and everything seems to be working fine when i tried to build my code this is the error i am getting. After doing some goggling i found that the local host is causing problem(I may be wrong ). I am not a database guy but can do stuff around. Please help me out. Trying to resolve this since 2 weeks.

listener.ora

```
**# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
**# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.****

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

**lsnrctl start**

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-APR-2015 09:45:39

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1//bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/log/diag/tnslsnr/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                07-APR-2015 09:45:39
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/log/diag/tnslsnr/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-APR-2015 10:08:50

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                07-APR-2015 09:45:39
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 23 min. 10 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/log/diag/tnslsnr/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully










SQL> startup 
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
SQL> exit                        
Disconnected
[root@tfdevvm oracle]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_tfdevvm-lv_root
                       60G   24G   34G  41% /
tmpfs                 3.0G  584K  3.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   71M  389M  16% /boot
/dev/sda3              15G   11G  3.2G  78% /media/tf_extn
[root@tfdevvm oracle]#
```

Comment: This question has nothing specific to ATG. It should not tagged as 'atg'.

Answer (score 0):

Your database instance isn't running. Fire up!

```
$. oraenv -- note the dot! input your SID.
$sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL>startup -- the database will register to the listener automatically.
```

Now you will have some output in your listener control.

Comment: . oraenv 
ORACLE_SID = [orcl] ? 
The Oracle base for ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 is /u01/app/oracle

Comment: **sqlplus / as sysdba** 

_SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Apr 7 12:06:13 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


Enter user-name:_

Comment: I am getting the error as mentioned. **ORA-12547.** @Bjarte Brandt

Comment: Is the ORACLE_SID correct? Please output $cat /etc/oratab

Comment: @Bjarate Brandt                      $ cat /etc/oratab
 This
`# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:Y
[oracle@tfdevvm ~]$`

Comment: You are having issues with premissions for your oracle binaries. Please have a look here: https://oracledbamasters.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/ora-12547-tns-lost-contact/

Comment: i have now access to the sqlplus.            `sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 9 00:18:25 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password: 
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup 
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system`

Comment: This means that the "memory_target" init param is too large for the available memory in /dev/shm.

Comment: df -h               
**Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_tfdevvm-lv_root
                       60G   24G   34G  41% /
tmpfs                 3.0G  584K  3.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   71M  389M  16% /boot
/dev/sda3              15G   11G  3.2G  78% /media/tf_extn **

Comment: @PhilSumner  included the memory df -h to the question please check it.

Comment: You need to check that the memory_target parameter is smaller than the available space in /dev/shm.